# Pycharm suspends remote debugging after connect

Tags: remote-debugging, pycharm

I've setup a remote debugging configuration in PyCharm based on [this link](http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2010/12/python-remote-debug-with-pycharm/). Despite the fact that I unmarked the `Suspend after connect` option, the debugger suspends upon connect and I must manually resume the program on each run.

Is there a way for the remote debugger *not* to suspend on connect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try passing `suspend=False` to `pydevd.settrace()` in case PyCharm has some problem with applying this setting itself.